# I've met the requirements for a badge, why hasn't it been awarded yet?

Tags: support, badges

I recently edited and answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732003/how-can-i-do-the-same-animation-like-in-google-play-or-chrome-omnibox-on-android/29733342), but didn't get the **Explainer** badge (both actions were done within 12hrs, answer score > 0). That said, the progress counter for the **Refiner** and **Illuminator** badges changed from 0 to 1. Is this a known bug or should I wait a bit longer?

Comment: As a rule, it's worth waiting for midnight UTC to roll around first...

Comment: Wait a bit: mine didn't come in immediately either, but it came by midnight (I think).

Comment: Relevant SE Meta Link: [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)

Comment: We should make a "Patience, Daniel-san" badge for people who wait for than 24 hours for their badge to show up...

Answer (score 25):

Not all badges come instantly or even within a few minutes of you meeting the criteria. It will depend on how expensive the query is to run, but you can usually guarantee that you'll have the badge once UTC midnight (+- an hour or two) comes round.

I would expect that the Explainer badge as it has to check your answer time against the time the question was edited and whether that editor was you or not would be one of the expensive ones.