# Why didn't I get the Explainer badge for this answer and edit?

Tags: support, badges

I answered and edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680500/safe-general-config-file-for-webapp/30683199) within 12 hours from each other, got my edit accepted and answer upvoted, and duly [waited a while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290795/4962868) for the Explainer badge to be awarded. I didn't get it. What gives?

Comment: Yes, that's where I eventually found the answer and it's arguably duplicate. But I almost didn't find the answer there; it's easy to overlook this one disqualifying point in the answer. However, I accept that this may not be enough reason to keep this as a separate Q&A.

Comment: Keep in mind that duplicates aren't necessarily a bad thing.  More reading on why [a certain amount of duplication is good](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that but it makes perfect sense and rhymes with my own reason for adding this self-answered question. I will stop worrying and click "yes, my question is a duplicate!" next time. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I wasn't eligible; it took me a little while to find out [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator/240302#240302). Not just any approved edit qualifies; it has to modify body or title. My edit only added two tags.

Here's [another reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/295533) that clearly states tag-only edits don't qualify.